# How can I catch RSP and RIP corruption exceptions in Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, exception

I am working on a crash handling system for my Windows desktop application, and not sure the best way to catch some exceptions. Here are 3 simple functions that crash:

```
crash_av proc
  xor rax, rax
  mov qword ptr [rax], 0
  ret
crash_av endp

trash_rip proc
  push 0
  push 0
  ret
trash_rip endp

trash_rsp proc
  xor rsp, rsp
  ret
trash_rsp endp
```

Using `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`, I'm only able to catch `crash_av`.

Using `AddVectoredExceptionFilter`, I'm only able to catch `crash_av` and `trash_rip`.

But I am unaware of any way to catch `trash_rsp` at all. Is it possible? Are there other crash scenarios I should be looking out for? Is there a canonical way to capture *all* of these crashes, reliably?

Comment: There is no way to catch *"crashes"*. It is possible to intercept unhandled SEH exceptions, but your code may or may not raise one.

Answer (score 0):

any exception handler executed in context of thread, in which exception occurred. in case `trash_rsp` - let ask - which must be `rsp` (stack pointer) when exception begin handled ? when you corrupt `rsp` (go out of stack space) - game is over for your process. any internal handler can not recover from this.

in case `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` exist one point - [`UnhandledExceptionFilter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681401(v=vs.85).aspx) called only when debugger not attached to your process. so if debugger attached - [`UnhandledExceptionFilter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681401(v=vs.85).aspx) not called. you bad test [`UnhandledExceptionFilter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681401(v=vs.85).aspx) must be called for both `crash_av` and `trash_rip` if debugger not attached. otherwise must not be called for both.

`AddVectoredExceptionHandler` called for any exception (except rsp out of stack space) independent from debugger attached or no. of course if debugger not handle exception on first chance and another  `AddVectoredExceptionHandler` not handle exception before your